# Ignore index to avoid boolean mask throwing "Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer"

Tags: python, pandas

I have this indexed dataframe:

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [False, False, False], 'b': [True, False, False]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
       a      b
a  False   True
b  False  False
c  False  False
```

And I have boolean mask (non-indexed) dataframe of equal dimensions:

```
In [17]: mask = pd.DataFrame({'a': [False, False, False], 'b': [True, False, False]})

In [18]: mask
Out[18]:
       a      b
0  False   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
```

That I want to subset like so:

```
In [19]: df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1)]
```

However this throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-54eb24f8acdb> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1)]

… 

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

How can I "ignore" the index in this case?

Comment: `df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1).values]` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both indexes has to be same, so work:

```
mask.index = df.index
print (df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1)])
       a      b
b  False  False
c  False  False
```

Or use suggestion from [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821891/ignore-index-to-avoid-boolean-mask-throwing-unalignable-boolean-series-provided/44822502#comment76623894_44821891) comment - convert to numpy array - then index values are not used because does not exist:

```
print (df.loc[~mask.any(axis=1).values])
       a      b
b  False  False
c  False  False
```